# BackboneJS caching http results

Tags: backbone.js

Need help on caching http requests in a BackboneJS application. I'm using deferred which I think is from JQuery. The code I'm playing with is

```
this.someItem.fetch({timeout:60000, cache:true}).done(function() {
  // do your stuff
  console.log('testing ....');
}
);
```

But it's not working. I don't see (cached) in network tab once the exact url gets called again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using raw Backbone? I browsed a few pages and found that this feature is provdided if you require Backbone fetch plugin.

http://floatleft.com/notebook/backbone-fetch-cache/

Comment: Ok, I'll check it out